# c++ class objects in concurrent threads

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I tried to launch a class who has a running thread. When I create the objects it creates a bad group of objects. I really don't understand what is happening. The idea is create 10 objects  with their threads and get the messages from the thread f2. I need one queue by worked thread by specs. I use mutex because I thing c++ std:queue is not thread-safe. The problem is when main is running It shows like most of the objects are the same. I post the code:

```
class classOne {
public:
    classOne(int n, std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> prompr_mtx_ptr);
    ~classOne();

    int m_id;
    bool m_stop;
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_mtx;
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> m_classOne_thread;
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_prompr_mtx_ptr;
    std::shared_ptr<std::queue<std::string>> m_queue;

    void classOne_thread_body();
};

classOne::~classOne() {

}

classOne::classOne(int n, std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> prompr_mtx_ptr):
        m_id(n),
        m_prompr_mtx_ptr(prompr_mtx_ptr)
{
    m_queue = std::make_shared<std::queue<std::string>>();
    m_mtx = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();
    m_stop = false;
    m_classOne_thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&classOne::classOne_thread_body, this);
}

void classOne::classOne_thread_body() {
    int watchDog = 0, debugDog = 0;
    m_prompr_mtx_ptr->lock();
    std::cout<<"[ Thread "<<std::to_string(m_id)<<" ] Started"<<std::endl;
    m_prompr_mtx_ptr->unlock();
    while (!m_stop) {
        m_mtx->lock();
        if (!m_queue->empty()) {
            m_prompr_mtx_ptr->lock();
            std::cout<<"[ Thread "<<std::to_string(m_id)<<" ] Received message: "<<m_queue->front()<<std::endl;
            m_prompr_mtx_ptr->unlock();
            m_queue->pop();
            watchDog = 0;
        }
        m_mtx->unlock();

        ++watchDog;
        if (watchDog>= 1000) { m_stop = true; }
        if (watchDog - debugDog > 100) {
            m_prompr_mtx_ptr->lock();
            std::cout<<"WatchDog: "<<watchDog<<std::endl;
            m_prompr_mtx_ptr->unlock();
            debugDog = watchDog;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void f2(int n, std::vector<classOne> elements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        for(std::vector<classOne>::iterator it=elements.begin(); it!=elements.end(); ++it) {
            it->m_mtx->lock();
            it->m_queue->push(std::string("Message "+std::to_string(i)+" to thread "+std::to_string(it->m_id)+" from "+std::to_string(n)));
            it->m_mtx->unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1; // t1 is not a thread
    int generators = 10;
    std::vector<classOne> genClassOnes;
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> prompr_mtx_ptr = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();

    for (int i = 0; i < generators; i++) {
        genClassOnes.push_back(classOne(i, prompr_mtx_ptr));
    }

    std::thread t2(f2, 1, genClassOnes); // pass by value
    t2.join();

    for (std::vector<classOne>::iterator iter=genClassOnes.begin(); iter!=genClassOnes.end(); ++iter) {
        iter->m_classOne_thread->join();
    }
}
```

And this is the wrong output:

```
[ Thread 3 ] Started
[ Thread 8 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Started
[ Thread 9 ] Received message: Message 0 to thread 9 from 1
```

Comment: I would be very wary of storing `classOne` objects in a vector like that. What if the vector resizes after five elements? Yes, all objects will be copied to the new vector, but the running threads will **still use the old addresses** for their `this` pointer. At least heap-allocate the `classOne` objects with `new` and use a `vector<classOne*>`.

Comment: A minor comment: spawning a thread and then immediately `join`ing it is no better than executing the code directly.

Comment: Finally, once you get this working, read up on condition variables. Your consumer threads should block on condition variables and only wake up once the consumer delivers a message to their queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<classOne>` requires `classOne` to be copyable if you call `push_back` or `resize`. Whereas `std::list<classOne>` doesn't require `classOne` to be copyable, so that you can remove all those `shared_ptr`s.

Use a condition variable to let a thread know that there are new elements available in the queue.

Working example:

```
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

class classOne {
    int m_id;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cnd;
    std::mutex* const m_prompr_mtx_ptr;
    std::queue<std::string> m_queue;
    std::thread m_classOne_thread;

    void classOne_thread_body();

    template<class F>
    void log(F&& f) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_prompr_mtx_ptr);
        f(std::cout);
    }

public:
    classOne(int n, std::mutex& prompr_mtx_ptr);

    ~classOne() {
        this->stop();
        m_classOne_thread.join();
    }

    void post(std::string msg) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
            m_queue.push(move(msg));
        }
        m_cnd.notify_one();
    }

    void stop() { this->post({}); }

    int get_id() const { return m_id; }
};

classOne::classOne(int n, std::mutex& prompr_mtx_ptr):
    m_id(n),
    m_prompr_mtx_ptr(&prompr_mtx_ptr),
    m_classOne_thread(&classOne::classOne_thread_body, this)
{}

void classOne::classOne_thread_body() {
    log([&](std::ostream& s) { s <<"[ Thread "<<std::to_string(m_id)<<" ] Started"<<std::endl; });
    for(std::string msg;;) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
            while(m_queue.empty())
                m_cnd.wait(lock);
            msg = m_queue.front();
            m_queue.pop();
        }
        if(msg.empty())
            break;
        log([&](std::ostream& s) { s <<"[ Thread "<<std::to_string(m_id)<<" ] Received message: "<< msg << std::endl; });
    }
}

void f2(int n, std::list<classOne>& elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        for(auto& elem : elements)
            elem.post("Message "+std::to_string(i)+" to thread "+std::to_string(elem.get_id())+" from "+std::to_string(n));
    }
}

int main() {
    int generators = 10;
    std::mutex prompr_mtx_ptr;

    std::list<classOne> genClassOnes;
    for(int i = 0; i < generators; i++)
        genClassOnes.emplace_back(i, prompr_mtx_ptr);

    std::thread t2(f2, 1, std::ref(genClassOnes)); // pass by reference
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Awesome code, I am very grateful. There is many things I need to understand better like the log method you implement in classOne and this lock_guard but I will study those ones with the c++ reference. One special doubt, why you call the method post with an empty string when stop method is been calling? To ensure that the thread is going out of the while loop?. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JonSnow You are right, the empty string serves as a signal for the worker thread to break out of the queue handling loop and terminate.